# Custom IIdentity in WebSecurity class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Using the simple membership WebSecurity class, is there a way to extend this so that I can store a custom IIdentity in my authentication ticket? Or will I need to roll my own WebSecurity class (I hope not)?